# How can I create a 64-bit Windows 7 USB installer in a 32-bit environment?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation, 32-vs-64-bit

I have a 64-bit capable machine but accidentally installed a 32-bit version of Windows 7.  I have the 64-bit ISO and/or extracted files but can't find a way to create a bootable USB because I can't run **bootsect.exe** against the 64-bit files.

Is there a way to create a x64 bootable **USB** from within an x86 environment?

Comment: If you have any 32-bit media available, you can use the `bootsect.exe` version from that disc image.  Alternatively, I found a 32-bit version of `bootsect.exe` fairly easily off of Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently it's much simpler than I thought.  I just extracted the 64-bit ISO files onto the USB and rebooted the machine from the USB and it picked up the autorun configuration.

Comment: While as dumb as it sounds, it worked for me. I was on Windows 8.1 32bit and created 64bit Bootable flash drive just by copying files from ISO after mounting it.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC the Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool will also fail right at the end (*after* spending all that time copying the files to the USB!) because it cannot execute the 64-bit version of bootsect.exe present in the ISO.

[Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) or similar should work just fine though:

[image: 1]

Comment: If you want something [even simpler UI-wise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q8rI.png) then there's [WiNToBootic](http://www.wintobootic.com), but it requires the .NET framework (shouldn't be a problem on any recent version of Windows).

Answer (score 0):

[Win 64 from 32 bit](http://www.kossboss.com/windows64from32)

This worked for the PC that I just built (somehow forgot to buy a CD/DVD drive for it - feel dumb) and it also worked for a coworkers laptop install.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Definitely not spam, but please summarize the link. That way, your answer will remain useful even if the linked page goes down.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to get a 32-bit version of Bootsect.exe* and place it in the same folder you installed Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool.exe (WUDT) file. The default install directory of that file in Windows 8 is `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool\`, then run that WUDT tool again.

*Finding a legitimate version of Bootsect.exe can be tricky. For some reason, MS doesn't make it readily available. However, if you happen to have an ISO for a 32-bit Windows installer, you can find it in there. Just copy it from the /boot subfolder in that ISO to the WUDT install directory, as explained above, and re-run WUDT.